# Rails: split an HTML string between words only

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Given this variable:

```
=> str = " and then there was a gigantic <a href="link.com/bug.jpg">bug</a> on her nose!"
```

How can I write a function that instead of breaking wherever the character limit is reached like so:

```
=> str[0..33] = " and then there was a gigantic <a "
```

I have something that plays nicely with HTML and returns the closing tag if a tag is opened:

```
=> some_function(str) = " and then there was a gigantic <a href="link.com/bug.jpg">bug</a>"
```

I'd even settle for something that returns something worse, like:

```
=> worse_function(str) = " and then there was a gigantic"
```

Any help would be great. Obviously it'd have to have a rough character limit, or word limit even.

**Update**

So far I have this:

```
def friendly_excerpt(string, length)
  excerpt = string.split[0..length].to_s
  if excerpt.include?('<') && !excerpt.include?('>')
    friendly_excerpt = excerpt.slice(0..(excerpt.index('<')))
  end
  friendly_excerpt
end
```

Comment: Where's the code for the one you've currently got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this solution:

```
def friendly_excerpt(string, length)
  excerpt = string.split[0..length].join(' ')
  if excerpt.include?('<') && !excerpt.include?('>')
    friendly_excerpt = excerpt.slice(0..(excerpt.index('<') - 1)).strip
  else
    friendly_excerpt = excerpt.strip
  end
  friendly_excerpt
end
```

Seems to work nicely.

Comment: Seems better and cleaner than I did. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

1. Couont how many `<` is there in the string
2. check the index of all the `<`
3. remove the tag from the position of the `<` to `>`

so it would be something like:

```
def remove_html_tag(str)
  result = str
  tag_count = str.count('<')

  for i in 0..tag_count do
    index_1 = result.index('<')
    index_2 = result.index('>')
    result = result[0...index_1] + result[index_2..-1] 
    # the above line remove one html <> tag, and it repeats
  end

  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have clean truncation of strings containing HTML, rather than to write the function yourself, I'd recommend the gem [html_truncator](http://rubygems.org/gems/html_truncator). It uses Nokogiri to parse HTML and then handles truncation appropriately.

Example (many more on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/nono/HTML-Truncator)):

```
HTML_Truncator.truncate("<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>", 3)
# => "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor…</p>"
```

Note that it defaults to taking the truncation length argument in *words* rather than *characters*, but there is an option to use characters instead.

```
HTML_Truncator.truncate("<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>", 12, :length_in_chars => true)
# => "<p>Lorem ipsum…</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

The minutes I see HTML, I turn to Nokogiri because I can't handle dealing with begin and end HTML elements. I've tried and lost many times.  Assuming you have Nokogiri installed...

```
html_string = ' and then there was a gigantic <a href="link.com/bug.jpg">bug</a> on her nose!'
min_length = 33
res = Nokogiri.HTML(html_string)
nodes = res.elements.children.children.children #I wish I knew why all of these are needed.
nodes.reduce('') { |new_string, node| 
   break new_string if new_string.length > min_length; 
   new_string + node.to_html 
}
```